# PHP script to control background process

Tags: php, timer, process

I want to host a script, reacting to requests like:

`script.php?req=10`

that means, set a counter up every 10 ms...

This request is made multiple times with different values and the "timing" needs to be adjusted with every request until the value is 0

So for me there has to be some sort of background process with live adjustement that could be controlled out of the php script and i dont have the right idea how to solve this! Any idea is welcomed..

Thanks a lot,
Tobi

Comment: what part are you stuck on? do you have access to cron?

Comment: I think i need to have a script running the whole time in the background where i am able to change a variable… This is where i am stuck…

Comment: yeah, the reason I asked if you have cron is so you can start the script and keep it running, there is other ways like systemd but cron comes with most hosting. then think of the script which is run as a runner for other scripts and all it does is loop. then your job script call variables from a db or flatfile, which you update via a side-channel like HTTP, which then on next iteration the variable is used

Comment: see this old script for inspiration (read the comment) https://gist.github.com/lcherone/28b92af0f06c1224b30fe734a0d51877 where it says `### do your code`, include your script which queries a db of sorts for *variable*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON JOBS to accomplish this !

Here is the link to the website : https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: Thanks, but to my knowledge a CRON could be called just once a minute, i definitely need to be more precise with  something under a second… i think a CRON Job is not the right tool for that..

Comment: Then pass the thing you need with AJAX and set interval.